# What charsets do the major browsers support?

Tags: http, browser, character-encoding

The HTTP 1.1 `Accept-Charset` header allows a browser to specify which character encodings it accepts.  My questions are:

- For the major browsers, what values do they specify in the `Accept-Charset` header?
- Will a browser ever specify *different* `Accept-Charset` values based on domain or URL or any other factor?
- Do any of the major browsers "tolerate" character encodings not specified in the `Accept-Charset` header?  E.g. a server sends a response that explicitly specifies a different charset, or, the browser's [charset detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset_detection) detects a different charset?

Cheers.

Comment: Why would you use anything other than UTF-8? Every browser accepts it, and it quite nearly handles all languages out there.

Comment: The question isn't so much about what I'd use as it is about what's happening "in the wild".

Comment: UTF-8 makes some files much bigger than they need to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Accept-Charset` headers depend on browser locale. My Firefox sends
`ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7`
and Chrome sends
`ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3`
whereas IE, Opera, and Safari send no `Accept-Charset` header. But in, say, Russian or Japanese environment there is probably something else in place of ISO-8859-1.

The `Accept-Charset` headers are not of much use. They are meant to specify the browser’s preference in case the server can provide several alternatives, but if you wish to make your server do such things, would you really believe what browsers say? In my examples, all that the browsers say (if they say anything) is expressed preference for ISO-8859-1 over UTF-8 or other encodings and, in the Chrome case, additionally preference for UTF-8 over other encodings than ISO-8859-1.

I have never seen variation by domain or URL. Though possible of course, such variation would not make much sense. It is the browser’s own environment that we could expect to matter.

All the browsers in my test indicate, by the HTTP protocol, that any character encoding is acceptable. They do this by not sending an `Accept-Charset` at all or by including `*` in the header. What they can actually do is a different issue, and the View→Encoding menus in browsers are not necessarily exhaustive, but they give some idea of how many encodings the browser might support.

The HTML5 draft contains a lengthy discussion of [determining the character encoding](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html#determining-the-character-encoding). It is partly meant to be descriptive of current browser behavior, partly prescriptive or at least suggestive of what browsers should do, and distinguishing the two is not always easy. Note that the “locale language” in the suggested table of default encodings relates to the *browser* locale, not to the language of a web page. And this is about inferring the encoding when no better information is available, but obviously browsers with different locales are expect to be able to *handle* the encodings that they are suggested to infer.